# Disable radio button in bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I disable Bootstrap 3 radio buttons? If I start with the [BS3 example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) and add `disabled="disabled"` to each input element, there are no changes in appearance or behavior:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked disabled="disabled">Radio 1 (preselected)</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled">Radio 2</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled">Radio 3</label>
</div>
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6a3j46o/1/).

I guess this is because the disabled attribute is only applied to the now-invisible button and not the clickable text label, but I don't see anything in the BS3 docs about this.

Comment: you need to add the class disabled to the disabled ones !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `disabled` class to the label like this

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary disabled">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary active disabled">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary disabled">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/k6a3j46o/4/)

Comment: That's much better!  Is there any way to indicate which state is checked when the buttons are disabled?  It looks like the active class and checked attribute are ignored.

Comment: Yeah bootstrap doesn't seem to support both at the same time. Probably you'll have to write a custom style for that

Comment: this solution does not work in versions 3.3.4 to 3.3.6 it should be fixed in 3.3.7. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16703 inputs seems disabled but respond to click. I lost half an hour to figure out this....

Comment: @giammin thank you. To get around this bug for now, I am hooking a click function on the disabled labels and returning false. That seems to work.

Comment: @frax Good tip.  I don't think the bug was fixed in 3.3.7, so this is the only workaround.  I too have lost a fair bit of time thinking it was fixed, but changing that answer's fiddle to point at 3.3.7 verified for me that it has not been fixed.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by @giammin in the comments to the accepted answer, setting 'disabled' on the input elements doesn't work in 3.3.6 of bootstrap. (Current version at time of publication of this answer).

I was having *exactly* the same issue, and my solution was to use the CSS property "**pointer events**". This makes sure the element and children are never  a target of click events. However this is not a foolproof solution - users can still tab in and use space to click the hidden elements on a desktop browser.

```
.disabled-group
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you set this on your '*.btn-group*' element, you'll completely disable

```
<div class="btn-group disabled-group" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-primary disabled">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-primary disabled">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-primary disabled">
     <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
   </label>
</div>
```

The '*.disabled*' class is then optional - use it for graying out and 'cursor: not-allowed;' property.

The discussion of the fix solution is at this source:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16703

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use `pointer-events: none` and allowing the `not-allowed` cursor to be shown on hover. At least, I wasn't able to do it without some JS magic.

Comment: @self. - you're right, it's not. It's a trade-off between one and the other. But I found the pointer events to be more reliable. Of course, it's also been pointed out that your user can alt-tab to the disabled options too.

Answer (score 6):

For radio button groups, add class disabled to the one you wish disabled. 
Make sure you have something like this code:

```
$('.btn-group').on("click", ".disabled", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

This will get all your .disabled classed buttons inside the button groups also disabled. This works also for radio type button groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the above to disable an input[type='radio'] that is inside a label (bootstrap 3 style),

```
$("input[name='INPUT_RADIO_NAME']").prop("disabled", true);
$("input[name='INPUT_RADIO_NAME']").closest("div").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

The above to enable again,

```
$("input[name='INPUT_RADIO_NAME']").prop("disabled", false);
$("input[name='INPUT_RADIO_NAME']").closest("div").css("pointer-events", "auto");
```

You can also extend JQuery and create a dummy disable method (that you could upgrade with more functionality) like this,

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.disableMe = function () {
        // Validate.
        if ($.type(this) === "undefined")
            return false;

        // Disable only input elements.
        if ($(this).is("input") || $(this).is("textarea")) {
            // In case it is a radio inside a label.
            if ($(this).is("[type='radio']") && $(this).parent().is("label.btn")) {
                $("input[name='safeHtml']").closest("label").addClass("disabled");
                $(this).closest("div").css("pointer-events", "none");
            }

            // General input disable.
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        }
    };
    $.fn.enableMe = function () {
        // Validate.
        if ($.type(this) === "undefined")
            return false;

        // Enable only input elements.
        if ($(this).is("input") || $(this).is("textarea")) {
            // In case it is a radio inside a label.
            if ($(this).is("[type='radio']") && $(this).parent().is("label.btn")) {
                $("input[name='safeHtml']").closest("label").removeClass("disabled");
                $(this).closest("div").css("pointer-events", "auto");
            }

            // General input enable.
            $(this).prop("disabled", false);
        }
    };
    $.fn.toggleDisable = function () {
        if ($.type(this) === "undefined")
            return false;

        // Toggle only input elements.
        if ($(this).is("input") || $(this).is("textarea")) {
            var isDisabled = $(this).is(":disabled");

            // In case it is a radio inside a label.
            if ($(this).is("[type='radio']") && $(this).parent().is("label.btn")) {
                $("input[name='safeHtml']").closest("label").toggleClass("disabled");
                $(this).closest("div").css("pointer-events", isDisabled ? "auto" : "none");
            }

            // General input enale.
            $(this).prop("disabled", !isDisabled);
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Usage example,

```
$("input[name='INPUT_RADIO_NAME']").disableMe();
$("input[name='INPUT_RADIO_NAME']").enableMe();
$("input[name='INPUT_RADIO_NAME']").toggleDisable();
```

Answer (score -1):

In bootstrap if you want to disabled any input type or button, You just have to add bootstrap's .disabled class then your button become disabled.

**Like this**

```
<input type="radio" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Primary Button</button>
```